# How to open a Java application with arguments on Mac OS X?

Tags: java, macos, arguments, shortcut

I created a Java application that uses an argument from `main(String[] args)`. In Windows, I can open it by creating an `.lnk` file with the following target:

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaw.exe -jar ./theApp.jar theArgument
```

Is there any way to do this in Mac OS X without using command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a bash

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
$JAVA_HOME/java -jar ./theapp.jar theArgument
```

Comment: ./script.sh: line 2: /java: No such file or directory

Comment: Ok, it worked without `$JAVA_HOME/`. But I had to associate `.sh` files to the Terminal first. I'm not sure whether the potential user will want to to it - it's just uncomfortable a little. Isn't there a method to do it without associating `.sh` to the Terminal?

Comment: you can try the appify script. This will create an app from the bash script. https://gist.github.com/mathiasbynens/674099